# Регулярные выражения: выделение и исключение конткретного сочетания

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно, чтобы из строки: ite123ger223Atok23332ger324err00001ger244ger244ger123.
Выделились все ger***, кроме ger244.
Выделение всех ger*** было реализовано так: ger+[0-9A-f]* а как сделать исключение конроетного выражения ума не приложу.
regexp Perl. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.
***добавление*** А если надо исключить например ger244 и ger233?

Comment: `ger(?!244)[0-9A-f]*` или `ger(?!244(?!\d))[0-9A-f]*` (если нужно найти `ger2446`)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ!  А если надо исключить например ger244 и ger233?

Comment: `ger(?!2(?:33|44))[0-9A-Fa-f]*` или `ger(?!2(?:33|44)(?!\d))[0-9A-Fa-f]*`

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать

```
ger(?!244)[0-9A-Fa-f]*
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/8et9oS/1).
Если при этом нужно найти `ger2446`, но отсеять `ger244`, используйте

```
ger(?!244(?!\d))[0-9A-Fa-f]*
```

[См. другое демо](https://regex101.com/r/8et9oS/2).

**Подробности**

- `ger` - подстрока `ger`
- `(?!244)` - сразу справа от текущей позиции не должно быть `244`
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]*` - 0 и более цифр или букв от `a` до `f` и от `A` до `F`